# Creating a gitlab description template

Tags: gitlab

Currently I am trying to setup gitlab description templates, I have followed the steps under documentation and still of no use

Steps

1. Create a `.gitlab` directory and inside it `issue_templates` directory
2. Created a simple markup file with the following:

```
### Problem statement: 

<!-- Explain the problem in simplest way which could be understood by layman -->

###Solution(Versions if necessary):
<!-- Start with solution, think about how you are going to solve, then implement. -->
<!-- Add Versions(V1, V2 etc) incase there are better ways to solve the problem -->
```

Verified a few things:

Have checked the version of gitlab currently using and it is 13.2.4 Community Edition
According to documentation the steps are to be implemented in `master` and i created one

and still there is no change - is there something that i am missing

[Documentation Link](https://gitlab.box8.co.in/help/user/project/description_templates)

Comment: How do you know it does not work? Did you try to open an issue and check if the template is among the proposed ones?

Comment: Yes @vinzee post commit push, i tried creating a new issue and i get the default descripton, ``write a comment or drag a file here``

Comment: Is master your default branch?

Comment: The code is both in master and all necessary branches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a human error, forgot to name the template with `.md` extension

Answer (score 1):

Several things to check:

- Does `.gitlab/issue_templates/` exist?
- Does the template has a `.md` extension? (as @TheViralGriffin stipulated)
- Are the previous mentionned files located on the **default** branch (usually `master`, but it can be another one: check "Default Branch" in "Repository Settings" on GitLab)?